# How to make onclick event to work only once in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, onclick, vuejs3

this is the normal javascript code for calling onclick event only once:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;">This button works only once</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">This button works always</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        console.log("hello");
    }
</script>
</body>
```

the trick for normal javascript is this:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;">
```

But, now I want this functionality in vue.js and my button in vue.js is like following:

```html
 <input
     type="submit"
     value="Start"
     name="start_button"
     @click="start"
 />
```

Can anyone suggest me how to call event exactly once in vuejs....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`.once` event modifier](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers) to handle the event only once:

```html
<input @click.once="start">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-once-event-modifier)

Comment: this works. But, inside this function I applied validation to the input fields. So, if user clicked that button and forget to fill the required input field, than pop up open and he will write the text in that input field. But, after that he will not allow to submit the function because it called only once and that happened during validtion.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of the question. However, for your use case, you should probably just use a validation flag (via a Boolean prop) instead of disabling event handling.

Answer (score -2):

We can add `prevent` modifier to events
It is equivalent of Event.preventDefault() in javascript.

```js
 <input
     type="submit"
     value="Start"
     name="start_button"
     @click.prevent="start"
 />
```

Comment: `Event.preventDefault()` doesn't prevent the handler from being called again.